# Deploying my magento site on new Elastic Beanstalk environment

Tags: magento-1.9, aws

We have a t1.micro ec2 server right now. It has magento installed on it, which has been customized w various plugins and other custom development

I’ve successfully set up an elastic beanstalk LAMP environment and connected it to RDS.

I’d like to install our magento site on our elastic beanstalk environment and use it as our production environment, but am not sure how.

I know that deploys are handled on elastic beanstalk by uploading a zip file, but I have been unsuccessful so far at deploying working software.  I am not sure exactly what needs to be zipped, and I am not sure if I am missing/copying config files unnecessarily.

To this point I have:
Replicated the database from the t1.micro server into the RDS database.  Based on a few queries and browsing the tables, it seems like I did this successfully.

Zipping everything in our t1.micro /var/www/html folder (changing params in local.xml to RDS db host,user,pw), and uploading that folder, but am getting a stack trace:

[image]

Also - I originally had installed the sample elastic beanstalk test software successfully, so I know that there are no security group issues between my servers and RDS.

Ultimately, I would love some help on how to deploy customized magento to elastic beanstalk - what files & directories need to be included in the zip, and guidance on what files need to be changed. Any help for a n00b would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check error in error report file : /var/report/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had created a backup of my local.xml prior to making my changes and magento was loading both files.  I deleted the backup, and everything worked.  Found answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143060/move-magento-installation-to-new-server

Answer (score 0):

Check error in error report file : /var/report/**error no display in screen**

Comment: I am getting the following error:  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory";i:1;s:2373:"#0 /var/app/current/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect().     Any ideas?  I've checked local.xml and seems like I have entered everything appropriately.

Comment: Check with changing from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" in local.xml, if still not working try to restart server

Comment: After changing in local.xml file remove content of var directory.

Comment: I'm trying to connect to a RDS database, so have the hostname pointed to my RDS endpoint.  As far as removing contents of var directory, 
should I delete all of these files, folders and their contents?  58c054c386b55pos-magento-api-1.9.2.zip  cache  export  importexport  log  package  pos  report  resource_config.json  session  tmp

Comment: You have to remove all cache directory

Answer (score -2):

First go to your magento directory using command prompt and enable developer mode using below command :

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Using this command, you can get exception on front end. No need to go to log report to check the exception again and again.

Comment: This question is related to Magento 1 and you have given hint based on Magento 2.